# What is the symbol on R. Haim Huri's clothing?

Tags: clothing, symbols-symbology

[Hakham Haim Huri](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99) (1885 – 1957) was a Tunisian dayan that founded a yeshibhah in Djerba and wrote several books on Torah, Shas, derashoth, responsa, etc. I came across two different photographs of him wherein he has a large symbol that appears to be embroidered onto his clothing (it looks similar to the symbol of Sikkhism). Does anyone know what it was and whether it was religiously significant?

[image]

[image]